# Python Excel File Import only rows with array data and neglect non-array like data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My CSV file in the starting has a few instructions, inputs and then in the end array data. I want to import array data only. In the file, array data starts at 60th row.

[image]

Mycode:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename>csv')
```

Output:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 6, saw 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't import poorly formatted tables like that. Pandas can't tell that that is 3 separate tables. Either copy and paste the tables in 3 separate files/sheets and import the ones you need or specify the number of the rows to skip before importing the rest of the data using the skip row parameters of read_csv.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html